# C-style array of pointers to Objective-C objects under ARC

Tags: ios, malloc, automatic-ref-counting, arrays

I have a 2D array of pointers to Objective-C instances to keep track of game objects on a map grid. 
Now I am transitioning my code to ARC, and Xcode pointed the error. I knew pointers to objects aren't allowed as struct members, but this one caught me (almost) off guard.

I understand the rationale behind the ARC constrains, but:

1. I can't afford the overhead of objective-C arrays when looking up objects in the grid, and
2. The objects themselves are already owned by an `NSArray` ivar defined in the same class that has the C-style grid as an ivar; the c-style array is only a conveniently structured shortcut. Futhermore, when objects are removed from the owning `NSArray`, I set the corresponding grid slot to `NULL`.

That is, the 2D array (grid) is just a collection of fast (but dumb) pointers to objects safely retained somewhere else (the `NSArray` ivar).

Is there a way to get away with this using casts? For example, define and alloc my grid as:

```
void*** _grid;
```

instead of

```
MyMapObjectClass*** _grid
```

and use (appropriately bridged) casts between `void*` <-> `MyMapObjectClass*` when setting or getting the pointers in each slot?

**EDIT**: So here is how I solved it

I changed the ivar declaration as described above. In addition, when setting an entry of my look-up grid, I did this:

```
// (Done **Only Once** at map initialization) 
// _objectArray is an instance of NSMutableArray

MyMapObjectClass* mapObject = [[MyMapObjectClass alloc] init];

// ...configure map object, etc...

// Add to Obj-C array:
[_objectArray addObject:mapObject];

// Add pointer to 2D C array:
_grid[i][j] = (__bridge void*)mapObject;
```

When accessing the object at (x,y), I do the opposite:

```
MyMapObjectClass* object = (__bridge MyMapObjectClass*) _grid[x][y];

[object performSomeMethod];

// etc...
```

When removing the object from the map, I do this:

```
MyMapObjectClass* object = (__bridge MyMapObjectClass*) _grid[x][y];

[_objectArray removeObject:object];

_grid[x][y] = NULL;
```

Map objects are created once at the beginning of the game, and removed according to game progress. If I need to **replace** a map object for another, I would do this:

```
MyMapObjectClass* oldObject = (__bridge MyMapObjectClass*) _grid[x][y];
// (should mark as weak?)

[_objectArray removeObject:oldObject];    
_grid[x][y] = NULL;

MyMapObjectClass* newObject = [[MyMapObjectClass alloc] init];

[_objectArray addObject:newObject];

_grid[x][y] = (__bridge void*)newObject;
```

Comment: where is the line of code that ARC is pointing out?

Comment: Xcode doesn't seem to point out all errors at once, but instead in batches of 4-12. You fix some, and the next ones appear in the following check. The first error appeared in the ivar declaration of the C-array. And now, every assignment or comparison between obj-c pointer and void* is being signaled. I'm fixing it right now, and it looks like __bridge should work...

Comment: It's curious, some of the casts are 'suggested' by Xcode's autocorrect feature, but some are just marked as errors.

Comment: On a side note, the conversion is taking forever because I have **tons** of old-style singletons (Sound manager, texture manager, cache sprite VBO manager, GameCenter manager you name it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circumventing ARC using casts is generally a bad idea. The better way would be to [disable ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for your map.m (or break out just the lookup part into a separate class).Then do manual memory management inside it with `retain` / `release` and the C structures you like, as long as you do it correctly it will work fine and you will be able to call it from other classes, avoiding the overhead of nested `NSArrays` etc..

Comment: But the pointers I have work like __unsafe_unretained. I am not circumventing ARC, just using __bridge; there should be no problem. I am keeping the NSArray and the C array in sync. The objects are retained by the NSArray (as per ARC). There is no danger of dangling pointers.

Comment: To put it clearer: I have an ARC-friendly NSArray that owns my objects, 100% Objective-C, 100% ARC. **In addition**, I have a 'look up table' to gain quick access to my objects in a row/column fashion. The table entries are correctly updated to NULL when I remove an object from the NSArray (which gets deallocated), to avoid dereferencing a zombie.

Comment: I would still recommend factoring it into a separate file and disable ARC for that file, as that is a more future-proof solution. If Apple ever decides to change the semantics you will not end up with compile errors for sketchy casts. Your solution will work though.

Comment: I understand. But this class is part of a whole group of files (Map Object, Map, Map Layer, etc.) and I'd rather have it all-or-nothing. I know ARC and non-ARC interoperate OK, but using these casts doesn't 'feel' worse than mixing compiler modes.

Comment: Still, there seems to be no better way out, besides what I chose to do, so I'm giving you the tick and an up-vote ;)