# Release Objective C object in C-array with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I don't know how to release an Objective-C object that I have stored in an old-fashioned c-array.

(Remark: While writing this after much searching, I think I found a bug in the test-code so this seems to be a solution rather than a question.  Well, I've spent a lot of time on it so I'll post it anyway...)

I'd like to convert older code to ARC, because I am spending too much time on debugging memory-management related bugs (sorry---the retain/release rules simply aren't hardwired in my spine, and it takes me literally hours to find a missing retain, because the errors pop up at unrelated moments, probably during or after memory cleanup).

So I have some existing code with c-style arrays (say a two-dimensional array of `UILabel*`'s),  where I can happily `calloc()` the pointers and access them through some `array[col*colstride+row*rowstride]`, where `array` is of the type `UILabel **`;  Let's assume the `UILabel*`s are filled at random order, so I can't use an `NSMutableArray` for that.

Now in ARC, the compiler wants me to make the type of `array` to be `UILabel *__strong*`, it seems (some people write that as `__strong UILabel **`).

What I don't understand is how I can tell ARC to release the `UILabel` objects when it is time to do so (say in the `dealloc()` of my object that uses the c-array). In trying to understand the problem, I have a small set of objects, `Memory` and `MemoryUnit`, the former trying to store a large c-array of the latter.

```
-(Memory*)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    MemoryUnit * unit = [[MemoryUnit alloc] init];
    array = (__strong id *) calloc(sizeof(MemoryUnit*), 1024);
    array[0] = unit;
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
  for (int i=0; i<1024; i++) array[i]=nil;
  free(array);
}
```

In `MemoryUnit` we have the objects to be stored in the c-array (so this `MemoryUnit` is in the place of the `UILabel` mentioned above).  For testing I had the code

```
-(void)dealloc {
  NSLog(@"removed %x", (int)self);
}
```

in its `dealloc()` for debugging.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer rather than appending it to the question. It is much easier to nderstand, and it makes it possible to link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*As Bryan said, we need an answer in the stack overflow system.
So I do:*

**Solution**

Apparently, setting the array element of type `MemoryUnit *__strong` to `nil` causes the object to be released, as if this element had been declared in a `@propetty` and `@synthesize` pair of statements. This is actually suggested in [C-style array of pointers to Objective-C objects under ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155275/c-style-array-of-pointers-to-objective-c-objects-under-arc) I think

(I found the documentation in XCode very terse, and the ARC compiler definitions only told me what was not allowed rather than giving a hint on how to do things correctly.)