# Creating a dynamic 2D pointer array of NSObjects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I want to store a 2D array of NSObjects using C pointer arrays. I read another StackOverflow question which said that it's possible to do this as follows:

```
id myArray [10][10];
```

However I want to allocate the memory dynamically because I don't know how big the table will be before hand.

I understand how to create a 2D pointer array for standard C variable types but I don't know how to do it for the id type. If I were using an int, I'd do something like this:

```
int ** myArray = (int**) calloc (10, sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    myArray[i] = (int *) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
}
```

Any ideas how to do this with the id data type?

Comment: Also, if I do sizeof(id) it asks me if I want to use use __bridge which doesn't look right.

Comment: For your `int` example, the initial call should be a `int **`, using `sizeof(int *)`.  What you've got doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, but my real question is about specifically storing the id data type. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting answer and related to what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155275/c-style-array-of-pointers-to-objective-c-objects-under-arc

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ARC (which you probably should be) creating a C array of `id` type objects is going to be more trouble than it's worth.  You need to both `calloc` and `free` the array in the usual (non `id` way) and you *also* need to annotate the `id` objects like `id __strong myArray = …`  The other thing that's really counterintuitive but is required to make sure the elements in `myArray` are deallocated correctly is to explicitly set each element of `myArray` to nil before you free myArray.

So anyway, it's a lot of trouble and there are several gotchas to work around.  You should just use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`.  With the latest versions of `llvm` you can still access the arrays using "C style" syntax, like `myArray[x][y] = someObject;`.

Comment: I'm using a C array because this code needs check a large grid of numbers many times per second on the UI thread so efficiency's very important.

Comment: Are you sure `NSMutableArray` is really that inefficient?  I mean, yea it'll probably be less efficient, being a general purpose kind of thing, than well written single purpose code using lower level APIs, but don't fall into a premature optimization trap.

Anyway, like I said, you can do this.  The code will look very similar to your non-id code snippet.  You have to annotate the `id` types with the `__strong` keyword and you have to explicitly set your objects to nil, like `myArray[i][j] = nil` (for all `i` and `j`) before freeing your arrays, to make this work correctly under ARC.

Comment: I agree with the above; if speed is an issue then you probably don't want to be marshaling values into & out of NSObjects (in C array, NSArray's or otherwise).